# Getting wrong array php sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have an table called user like this

```
id | user
 1 | test
 2 | test1
```

I have an query like this:

```
$arr = array(0 => 1 , 1=> 2);
$sql = "SELECT user 
    FROM user 
    WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$arr).") 
    ORDER BY id";
$gg = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(!$gg) {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
} else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($gg)) {
        print_r($row[0]);
    }
}
```

Ouput always shows as `testtest1`
but i want it in array like 
`([0] => test, [1] => test1)` 
or even `test,test1` is ok but it should work outside loop as well. Help appreciated.

Comment: and where is the error? you print the array with key 0 so add that value tu an array and it's done

Comment: The amount of keys can vary and I wont be knowing how much are there

Comment: what array do you want to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array, then print the array. (And/or do whatever you want with the array)

E.G:

```
$arr = array(0 => 1 , 1=> 2);
$sql = "select user from user where id IN (".implode(',',$arr).") ORDER by id";
$gg = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$arrayOfResults = array();

if(!$gg){
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($gg))
    {
        array_push($arrayOfResults, $row[0]);
    }

    print_r($arrayOfResults);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_array($gg, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`
will return you an associative array. you can verify using `var_dump($row)`
also, you can use `MYSQLI_NUM` (for index as number) or `MYSQLI_BOTH` (for index as number as well as column name) instead of `MYSQLI_ASSOC`

otherwise you can also use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`  [e.g. here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.html)